# How to open pdf file in browser

Tags: java, pdf, browser, inline, content-disposition

I'm trying to open a pdf file in which has been exported from a repository. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
ConnectionManager con = new ConnectionManager();
String id = request.getParameter("uname"); 
String objname = request.getParameter("pass");
Properties prop = new Properties();
//ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("query");
//prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("query.properties"));
String uname = "DmAdmin";
String pass = "<pass>";
String docbase = "QDocs";
String ext = new String();
IDfSession ssn = con.getSession(uname, pass, docbase);
sysObj = (IDfSysObject)ssn.getObject((IDfId)new DfId(id));
//ByteArrayInputStream buf = sysObj.getContent();
//sysObj.getFile("C:\\Users\\rsaha04\\Downloads\\"+objname+".pdf");
String path = "C:\\Users\\rsaha04\\Downloads\\";
String filename = path + sysObj.getObjectName().toString();

IDfCollection coll = sysObj.getRenditions(null);
if (coll != null)
{
    while (coll.next())
    {
        String format = coll.getString("full_format");
        {
            if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))
            {
                ext = "pdf";
                System.out.println("extension set: "+ext);
            }
        }
    }
    
    filename = filename+"."+ext;
    sysObj.getFileEx(filename, ext, 0, false);
}
con.closeConnection(ssn);
//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+filename);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename='"+filename+"'");
```

I'm able to open the pdf file in adobe acrobat reader but it is failing for browser with this error.[image]

Please help me understand where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: How do you write the pdf file into the response? You left out the important part

Comment: @f1sh I'm sorry, this is the first time I'm coding something like this so I'm not really sure how to do it actually. It will be really great if you can guide me here.

Comment: You need your server to respond with a pdf file. You set the response headers, but your code never writes the pdf data into the response.

Comment: Oh! man. Thank you so much. I've fixed it now. If you could write your comment as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, i wrote this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your server to respond with a pdf file. You set the response headers, but your code never writes the pdf data into the response.

Do that using

```
response.write(bytesFromPdfFile)
```